# Search column name having specific value in tables in certain database

Tags: sql, database-schema

Is there any way I can search a column having specific value I am trying to find through all tables in a database? 
For example I have

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%VersionID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Which I found from searching. It gives me the table names that "versionID" column exists, but how can I search to return table names that for example have a value of "35" for that column.

Thanks in advance,

---

I apologize, maybe I am not being clear in my request. Maybe this cannot be done in SQL because I have not found anything through my research. But let me clarify.

Running this script

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%factor%'
--and table_name in (Select name from sysobjects where ratingVersionID = 35)
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Will return this for example:
[image: Query Results]

But let say, the "factor" column in "AutoAge_Factor" table does NOT HAVE any records matching to "35". How can I eliminate that table from returning in the results. But I would really prefer the format of the results be this way because I would like to use this return as a loop and do some other stuff within the loop.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This modification to your sql will generate more SQL that you can run

```
SELECT 
    'select '''+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'.'+t.name + ''', '+c.name + ' from ' 
      + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'.' + t.name
      + ' where ' + c.name + ' = 35'

FROM sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ID%' 
ORDER BY schema_name(schema_id), t.name
```

You could make the SQL run automatically if necessary, but the syntax for that depends on your platform. Alternatively, copy the results into your query tool and run them, if that suffices

Comment: podiluska: your SQl works great! Do you know if the results can be formatted in the same way the SQL I provided? Where it just lists the tablesNames...basically, I intend to loop over those tables(tables that have that "versionID" with that value) and eventually insert some stuff. Thanks again!

Comment: This outputs new queries, the only way I know of to run those is with a cursor, is it possible to make it in one query without cursor, in case I just want to get all table names where column x=y ?

Answer (score 0):

> select s.name, c.name  from sys.columns c     inner join sys.tables s
>   on s.object_id = c.object_id    where c.name like'%35%'

This will give you the columns with 35 and the associated table.

Comment: I was looking for a script that will return tables having that "versionID" and that the "versionID" column has a value of "35" Your script just returns tables with column of 35:)

Answer (score 0):

> declare @tableName varchar(100), @colName varchar(100) declare
>   @sqlStatement nvarchar(100)
>
> declare tablelist cursor for  select s.name, c.name  from sys.columns
>   c  inner join sys.tables s  on s.object_id = c.object_id where c.name
>   like'%YourSearchCondtion%' OPEN tablelist FETCH NEXT FROM tablelist
>   into @tableName, @colName
>
> while  @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
>
> SELECT @sqlStatement = 'SELECT ' + @colName + ', * FROM ' + @tableName
>   +  ' WHERE ' + @colName + ' NOT LIKE ''%35%'''
>
> exec sp_executesql @sqlStatement
>
> -- Here you can get the table that you dont want and add to a temp table.. PRINT CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR)
>
> FETCH NEXT FROM tablelist     INTO @tableName, @colName END
>
> CLOSE tablelist DEALLOCATE tablelist GO

Comment: I think this is what you are expecting. May be not exact, but you can tweak it I hope