# Fetching the columns of a MySQL table based on the values of the column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the column names of a table of the following format:

```
id | error 1 | error 2 | error 3 | error 4 |
--------------------------------------------
 1 |    1    |    0    |    0    |    1    |
-------------------------------------------
 2 |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |
```

I need to retrieve the column name whose value is 1. Instead of doing 
"Select * from table where id = 'someid'" and then filtering out, is there a way to hit the column names directly from the query?

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question. Correct me if I'm wrong, those other fields are columns too, right? Select them just as you would the 'id' column

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the column names say, the object with id = 1 has error 1 and error 4. I need to query with the value but i wont need the value.

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan in your case row id=1 has two 1 in `error 1` and `error 4` so what title should query return?

Comment: it should return error1 and error4

Comment: 8-0 :-) and how many rows must return query?

Comment: just one row, because im mapping it with the id

Comment: if one row - how can it return 2 values: `error 1` and `error 4`? do you want them as concatenated string?

Comment: Yup thats exactly what im looking at.

Comment: May be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637733/search-column-name-having-specific-value-in-tables-in-certain-database)?

Comment: Did you create this DB, because this seems an absolutely ridiculous way to go about modeling things...

Comment: Yes. Can you just tell me whats wrong? :)

Comment: the goal you try to achieve is wrong :-) for example, if you could keep `error 1` instead of 1 as value in the `table`.`error 1` that would simplify the query a lot

Comment: I just did... your data model is what is wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be **MUCH** better to just do a normal SQL query and then process the data in your PHP code, you *can* use `CASE` clauses here to get it done in SQL:

```
SELECT id,
  ( CASE WHEN `error 1` = 1 THEN 'error 1' END ),
  ( CASE WHEN `error 2` = 1 THEN 'error 2' END ),
  ( CASE WHEN `error 3` = 1 THEN 'error 3' END ),
  ( CASE WHEN `error 4` = 1 THEN 'error 4' END )
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(',',t2.e1,t2.e2,t2.e3,t2.e4) as err FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, 
    CASE WHEN `error 1`= 1 THEN 'error 1' ELSE NULL END AS e1,
    CASE WHEN `error 2`= 1 THEN 'error 2' ELSE NULL END AS e2,
    CASE WHEN `error 3`= 1 THEN 'error 3' ELSE NULL END AS e3,
    CASE WHEN `error 4`= 1 THEN 'error 4' ELSE NULL END AS e4
  FROM table1

) as t2
on table1.id=t2.id
```